# 11pt font size with aip style option and REVTEX document class

Tags: fonts, fontsize, revtex, journal

While preparing a document for submission to J. Math. Phys., much to my surprise, I found myself unable to typeset it with a font size of 11 pt. I include a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[aip, jmp, showpacs, superscriptaddress, floatfix, nofootinbib, 11pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Irrespective of what font size I specify in the header (except 10pt), the output always appears in 12pt. I have tried `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` and enclosing my entire document within `{\fontsize{11pt}{13.2} ... }` but that does not seem to work either.

I was wondering if there could be a workaround to this problem, perhaps by overriding the default behavior. Since the underlying document class is REVTEX and both aip and aps use the same font styles, I don't understand why 11pt works with one (the latter) but not with the other. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There exist a `aps11pt4-1.rpx` but nothing similar for aip. It is naturally possible to overwrite the font sizes but there is nothing built-in.

Comment: the only reason to use a publisher supplied journal size is to make manuscripts for that journal and so it is natural that they only allow the font sizes used in the publications concerned.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please clarify what you mean by overwriting the font sizes?

Comment: David is right here. And, there is nothing to understand. It is the given template that is a major customization. Indeed RevTeX is also not accepting BibLaTeX, but just BibTeX. This can cause you another headache. Latest version is 4.2f (2023). Read the Release Notes and understand what their priorities are. https://journals.aps.org/revtex ; If you're not publishing, think it through. If it a go (the usualy LaTeX approach), but know your requirements and set targets, when to drop non-suitable LaTeX codes.